safe divide command for pgfmathparse to enable equality checks involving division by zero
I want to check if two quotients are the same using \pgfmathparse{}. I want it to work even if one quotient divides by zero. Clearly 3/0 and 0/3 are not the same, but \pgfmathparse{} stops at the division by zero.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{0}
\pgfmathparse{\a/\b == \b/\ba}
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
    Hi!
\else
    Bye!
\fi
\end{document}

I inquired with ChatGPT, and it suggested that I make a safeDiv command, like this:
% Define a custom macro to handle division by zero 
\newcommand{\safeDiv}[2]{% 
\pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(#2 == 0, "undefined", #1 / #2)}% 
\pgfmathresult%
}

but it is not working and raises a lot of errors.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\newcommand{\safeDiv}[2]{% 
\pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(#2 == 0, "undefined", #1 / #2)}% 
\pgfmathresult%
}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{0}
\pgfmathparse{\safeDiv{\a}{\b} == \b/\a}
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
    Hi!
\else
    Bye!
\fi
\end{document}


chatgpt always gives bad code, as far as I can tell, where tex/latex is concerned. you would be better reading the manual or looking at examples here ;).

Hello @cfr, I will keep that in mind.  I just read the section of mathematical expressions, but even the built-in divide doesn't handle division by zero.

The pgf function ifthenelse (as well as the ternary x ? y : z) always evaluates both the then and the else part, i.e., it is not lazy (see Why does pgfmaths's ifthenelse evaluate both expressions?). Therefore the approach suggested by ChatGPT and Pawan Mudde does not work.
Moreover, pgfmath supports NaN and infinity, but it needs a special handler, which makes it difficult to use inside an == comparison even if a \safeDiv function was able to return NaN values.
An easier approach is to use the LaTeX primitive \ifnum to determine whether or not the fractions should be calculated and only use \pgfmathparse if it is safe to do so. This works the best if you move the full check inside of a command.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\newcommand{\eqFrac}[4]{
\ifnum#2=0\relax%
\ifnum#4=0\relax\pgfmathparse{1}% both divide by zero, return equal
\else\pgfmathparse{0}\fi% first fraction divides by zero, second does not, return not equal
\else%
\ifnum#4=0\relax\pgfmathparse{0}% second fraction divides by zero, first does not, return not equal
\else\pgfmathparse{#1/#2 == #3/#4}\fi% neither divides by zero, calculate equality
\fi%
}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{0}
\eqFrac{\a}{\b}{\b}{\a}
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
    Hi! The fractions have the same result.
\else
    Bye! The fractions do not have the same result.
\fi

\noindent
3/0 == 6/10: \eqFrac{3}{0}{6}{10}\pgfmathresult\\
3/5 == 6/0: \eqFrac{3}{5}{6}{0}\pgfmathresult\\
3/0 == 6/0: \eqFrac{3}{0}{6}{0}\pgfmathresult\\
3/4 == 6/10: \eqFrac{3}{4}{6}{10}\pgfmathresult\\
3/5 == 6/10: \eqFrac{3}{5}{6}{10}\pgfmathresult

\end{document}

Result:

